# Serial communication by bluetooth hc-05

Tags: bluetooth, wireless

i am making a ultrasonic radar using stepper motor and ultrasonic sensor , and displaying the output over a software(processing 3) which looks like a radar ppi on display ...is it possible ot replace the usb cable with a bluetooth connection to send data (serial) instead of using a usb cable i want the setup to be remote ..i am using a instructable https://www.instructables.com/id/Acoustic-Radar-Display/ for coding i just need to know how to make it wireless over bluetooth ...just changing the com over processing 3 works or i need to do some changes in command mode of bluetooth

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: radar does not use sound, it uses radio waves ... you are building a sonar

Comment: i have tried with a hc-05 without mking any changes to arduino code just power bluetooth and after loading code connect xt rx pins and just change com port over processing 3 ...i am just confused to do it with one so i tried all but not working

Comment: yes i am building a sonar kind of thing which just have a radar type display just ..its a scaled model to depict working of radar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a Bluetooth Module [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074J5WMH1), that has an SSP profile, it will show up as COM port on your windows machine.

Now if you want to use the Arduino's Hardware Serial (i.e. keep using Serial.print() but for Bluetooth) then you will connect the module like this:

- Bluetooth HC06 TX to digital pin 0 (Arduino Rx)
- Bluetooth HC06 RX to digital pin 1 (Arduino Tx)

But remember, you load your code using these pins too. Arduino has a "USB-to-Serial" IC on board that uses those two pins. So now two entities trying to use those same pins (U2S and BT) i.e. you will have to disconnect U2S connections:

[image]

The above image is a snippet from the Arduino schematic. One way to disconnect those connections is to remove those two resistors. But then again, next time you want to load your code, you won't be able to use USB cable anymore.

So, I will suggest you to use **SoftwareSerial** and choose any other two pins for Bluetooth Module and change in the code wherever you were communicating with the Processing using Serial.println(). replace that with SoftwareSerial println().

Comment: i am using a hc-05 ...bluetooth module because it can do both asa slave and master , hc-06 is a only slave type...do u want me to make my hc-05 as a slave and do this ...here dosent it should be master because it(bluetooth) is sending data  to pc(prosessing 3) ???

Comment: Your Arduino is Master, so Bluetooth should be a slave.

Comment: i a using hc 05 for the same purpose and it have SSP profile .....and i am using the hardware tx rx pins only ..i a using hc 05 for the same purpose and it have SSP profile .....and i am using the hardware tx rx pins only ..just to upload code disconnect them then reconnect then is the only change needed ...

Comment: i just wanted to know ...with just attaching the bluetooth to the project and using outgoing connection com in pc (it shows incoming and outgoing com) to which bt is connected ..is it possible to make it wireless ..for all this do i just need to connect the bluetooth at correct braud i.e.115200 in the above case and change the com port at the processing 3 as the outgoing com of bluetooth ...i just want to make the project wireless like no usb cable ..since it s a com connection i am asking can it be replaced with a bluetooth connection ...please help me i am stuck in here ...

Comment: please go through code once and see if i need some changes in the coding of project ..thank u regards..its is part of a project which i need to complete but i am not able to do it as i am new to coding and finding out the possibilities

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just follow the connection that I mentioned in the Answer (D0, D1). In the code change the Baud Rate to 9600. Both in Arduino and Processing. HC-05 default baud rate is 9600.

Comment: i have tried but as soon as i put the TX Rx pins in hardware pins 0 and 1 ..the system stops ..i have changed the speed of HC-05 to 115200 via AT commands with 1 stop bit and 0 parity bit , AT+UART=115200,0,0...do i need to use software serials ..because the continuous "s" which r send to pc are using that connection or am i doing something wrong ...i cant use 9600 because thats too slow for the radar ... thank you for all ur help

Comment: When you connect your Bluetooth with Arduino using D0 and D1, is the USB cable from Arduino still connected to your PC?

Comment: yes it is connected ..i am like 1st running entire thing with usb and then give external power to arduino and then connect the bluetooth rx tx of HC-05 to arduino and then disconnect the usb cable..in this as soon as i connect tx rx pins to bluetooth the entire system stops  like the sweep stop over processing 3..which was running fine before this connection ..the usb is connected in this case as to get the sweep over processing 3 after this only i try to connect the rx tx and remove usb cable

Comment: Ok, the Arduino has a USB-to-Serial chip on board. And that is using D0 and D1. Without disconnecting those you won't be able to use those two pins. I think it is better to use the software serial. Choose any other two pins, connect Bluetooth there and wherever in the code you are sending something to the PC replace that with software serial.println()

Comment: I updated my answer too.

Comment: i have done changes in arduino ide as chaning all hard serials to software serials like serial.available to myserial.available(example) i changed every line with serial to myserial (myserial is my software serial)...and then connected the tx and rx of bluetooth changed the uart to 115200,0,0 for braud rate ....then paired the bluetooth with laptop saw the outgoing serial port of bluetooth (mine was com7) then changed the serial.list in processing 3 for the same (com7) port ..issues i am facing r (usb is not connected arduino is powered by a 9v battery through jack)

Comment: it shows the com port is busy ..sometimes it connects but the display displays the pings and the sweep for sometime ...like it wont work indefinitely ..not even for one complete sweep of radar ..and sometimes it just start too slow foe motor rotation ..but the biggest issue is the complete sweep thing ....to make it 360 i doubled the array at processing made additional graticules and increased the step count in arduino ide so basically i have got what i wanted but with the usb attached ...

Comment: to get it wireless i tried software serial and changes made were every serial event was chaned to software serial but its not working as desired .do i have to keep some serials as the original one and not change them to software serial ...only sending part need to be changed(azimuth direction distances ) or other things too like starting of the stepper at the click of switch and other serial.available events

Comment: do i have to create a separate port in processing or just changing the serial.list to the outgoing serial com of bluetooth is enough  (like this "Serial myBluePort;" while importing processing.serial) i am using the earlier created serial port the myPort for the same ..if i am not using it for usb wont just changing its serial.list should do the work